# repeater .net properties and methods

Tags: .net, asp.net, repeater

With a .NET repeater is there anyway to call methods in the #Eval('') directive?  For example, if I am binding to an object with a DateTime property, it would be really convenient to set #Eval("ADateTimeProperty.ToString('hh:mm')") or something along those lines.  Is the only option to create another property with that returns a formatted DateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. For your datetime issue, however, you can just use:

```
<%# ((DateTime)Eval("ADateTimeProperty").ToString("hh:mm") %>
```

If you wanted to call a method, you could do:

```
<%# MyCustomMehtod(Eval("ADateTimeProperty")) %>
```

And on the code-behind:

```
protected string MyCustomMethod(object input)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(input.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of the `Eval` method that takes a format string as a second parameter:

```
<%# Eval("ADateTimeProperty", "{0:hh:mm}") %>
```